# C Pointer assignments - global

Tags: c, pointers, global

The following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *msg = "Hello, World!";
char *p;

p = msg;

int main()
{
    puts(msg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

gives an error :  error C2040: 'p': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'

but when we change the pointer assignment p = msg within the main there are no errors?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *msg = "Hello, World!";
char *p;

int main()
{
    p = msg;
    puts(msg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any suggestions     ?

Comment: You can't have executable statements outside of functions. You can only put declarations there.

Comment: The compiler incorrectly assumes that by `p = msg;` you've actually meant `int p = msg;`, which yields the error you observe.

Comment: You could also combine two "global" rows making the compiler happy with `char *p = msg;`

Answer (score 0):

In C all the the variables that have been declared outside of the main function are initialized at compile-time, and because of this, all of them must be initialized with static assignments.
For example:

```
#include<...>
int a = 5; // constant initialization
char* str = "HELLO WORLD"; // constant initialization
int b; // declared but uninitialized
b = a; // ILLEGAL: this is not an initialization, so it can't be solved @compile-time
int c = a; // ILLEGAL: dynamic init: depends on a value(a), so it can't be solved @compile-time
int main(){
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

All the operations that are not properly static constant initializations must be done inside the main function, which is the only procedure launched at run-time.
Instead if you want to do provide some pre-processing control you can use `#define` directives, that are directives for the compiler just to increase code readability and avoid dealing with values directly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MSG = "HELLO WORLD"

char* msg = MSG; // constant initialization with MSG macro
char* p; // constant initialization with MSG macro


int main(){
    puts(msg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```